# Can't see soft coded subtitles of MP4 file

Tags: windows-xp, subtitles

I downloaded a movie on MP4 format. Information about the file mentioned that it contains soft coded english subs.

When trying to play it, subs don't show. I tried it on the following players: VLC, QuickTime, BS player and windows media player.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the subtitles aren't loading automatically.

In VLC, try right clicking, then go to Subtitles. If the soft-sub isn't there, it is because the video file hasn't got it.

Another thing you can do is to check the Codec Information. Open your mp4 file in VLC, go to Tools and afterwards go to Codec Information. If you see a broadcast with a Subtitle type, then it has the subtitles.